# How can I prove that this series converges: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3n^2}{2n^3+n+2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3n^2}{2n^3+n+2}$$

The ratio test was not conclusive.

I was thinking about proving that the series is > 1/n but don't know how to show it.

Comment: Use the limit comparison test against the harmonic series to prove _divergence_.

Comment: Ooooops I meant diverges*

Comment: Note that for $n\ge 2$, we have $$\frac{3n^2}{2n^3+n+2}> \frac{3n^2}{3n^3}=\frac1n$$

Comment: @ajotatxe For $n\ge 2$, the series is indeed dominant over the harmonic series.

Comment: @alex403 Please change the title to avoid confussion.

Comment: OP has asked "How can I ...?", and I have answered the OP's question instantly and perfectly. Then @Magdiragdag got confused, thinking that OP wanted a proof to be provided on a plate. Thus, I have humored Magdiragdag, hence I actually have provided a full proof in all the glory detail. Thank you, and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare it with the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{3n^2}{2n^3+n+2}}{\frac1n}=\frac32\in(0,+\infty).$$Therefore, the series diverges.

Comment: @MarkViola You are right. I have edited my answer.

Comment: What kind of test is this? When can I use it?

Comment: @alex403 It's the [comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test): if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ are series of real numbers greater than $0$ and if the limit$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}$$exists and it belongs to $(0,+\infty)$, then either both series converge or both series diverge.

Answer (score 2):

For $n\ge 2$,

$$\frac{3n^2}{2n^3+n+2}\ge\frac{3n^2}{2n^3+2n}=\frac1n\cdot\frac{3n^2}{2n^2+2}>\frac1n\cdot\frac{3n^2}{3n^2}=\frac1n$$

Answer (score 1):

Try the Limit Comparison Test.

Put $a_n = \tfrac{3n^2}{2n^3+n+2}$. The given series is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$. *Choose* the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$, where $b_n = \tfrac{3n^2}{2n^3} = \tfrac{3}{2n}$. (Our choice for $b_n$ was based on the dominant terms $3n^2$ and $2n^3$ found in the numerator and denominator of $a_n$.) Then
\begin{align*}
L = \lim \dfrac{a_n}{b_n} 
= \lim \dfrac{3n^2}{2n^3+n+2} \cdot \dfrac{2n}{3}
&= \lim \dfrac{6n^3}{6n^3+3n+6}\\
&= \lim \dfrac{6}{6 + \tfrac{3n}{n^3} +\tfrac{6}{n^3}} \\
&= \dfrac{6}{6+0+0} \\[1ex]
&= 1.
\end{align*}
Since $0 < L < + \infty$, both $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ behave the same way (by the LCT). Clearly, $\sum b_n = \sum \tfrac{3}{2n} = \tfrac{3}{2} \sum \tfrac{1}{n}$ diverges (it is a nonzero multiple of the divergent harmonic series). 
$$
\therefore \quad \sum a_n \text{ diverges}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{3n^2}{2n^3+n+2}\ \ge
   \ \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{3n^2}{2n^3+3n^3}\ =
    \ \frac 35\cdot\sum_{n=1}^N \frac 1n\,\ \longrightarrow\,\ \infty
$$
for $\ N\rightarrow\infty.$